# how to create this with flutter?

Tags: flutter, categories

how to create this with flutter ? please let me knw how to create like this category section using flutter because i want to create like this

[image]

**i tried but i couldn't get the correct layout for that** this is what i tried

```
Stack(children: [
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color(0xffCBCACD),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                ),
                                width: 150,
                                height: 100,
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      indexCatName,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    Positioned(
                                      top: 70,
                                      left: 110,
                                      child: Image(
                                        width: 80,
                                        image: NetworkImage(
                                            'https://pizzafactory.lk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Pizza-Pollo-Alla-Diavola-300x300.png'),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )),
                          ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this :

```
  Widget _test() {
return Container(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(0xffCBCACD),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  ),
  width: 150,
  height: 100,
  child: Stack(children: [
    Positioned(
      top: 20,
      left: 15,
      child: Text(
        '123',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: -30,
      right: -15,
      child: Image(
        width: 100,
        image:
            NetworkImage('https://pizzafactory.lk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Pizza-Pollo-Alla-Diavola-300x300.png'),
      ),
    ),
  ]),
);
```

}

Comment: you don't need the ``ClipRRect`` widget here, you can get a rounded border using the ``Container`` itself using the decoration property. ``decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)``

Comment: If I use decoration then the image at bottom right will not round

Comment: ``clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,`` property will work. :)

Comment: oh thank you, now I know it, I updated my answer

Comment: you can use ``.withOpacity(0.12)`` on the color to get a transparent color look.

Comment: also, the image should be the first child of the stack widget or else the text will get behind the image if the text is longer. :)

Comment: oh you are right, I got it