# How can I make my image stick to the borders as shown in the attachment?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, styling

This is my code and I tried to make it stick to the bottom right as in the attachment image but I can't seem to accomplish that. I tried to use the Row Widget to position it at the end but it doesn't seem to do much. Any tips since I'm new to the mobile development world?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class MenuCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.cardTitle,
    required this.pageDestination,
    required this.imageSource, required this.cardColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String cardTitle;
  final Widget pageDestination;
  final String imageSource;
  final Color cardColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
        child: Container(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, top: 50),
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: cardColor,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                cardTitle,
                style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    imageSource,
                    width: 75,
                    height: 75,
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create this with flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74534843/how-to-create-this-with-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

Set the image as a Container background image, then set the `DecorationImage` `alignment` property to `bottomRight` & `fit` property to `BoxFit.none`

Sample:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 100),
    width: 200,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage( //this
        image: AssetImage(imageSource),
        fit: BoxFit.none,//this
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight, //this
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      color: cardColor, 
    ),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          cardTitle, 
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        const Text(
          "2.9GB",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.white54,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Code snippet **[here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=56ba6ea1f6e9c61633dfbca138011c74)**.

Comment: I updated the code to set Decoration Image Box Fit to none

Comment: This makes my AssetImage size way too big and I can't seem to resize it to fit at the bottom right corner. Any suggestions?

Comment: What size of the asset?

Comment: The image asset size became too big and not contained inside the GestureDetector

Comment: I suggest , talk to your designer & request for an asset that fits on your use case. Or you may edit or file another question here for the  use case. Good luck :)

Comment: Try the scale property on DecorationImage , set it to 8 . and see if it help.